# Reason for Spring Batch running on single thread instead of multithreads

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

A spring batch is configured with multiple threads and runs perfectly with these threads but somehow once batch ran with only one thread and other threads were still in *STARTED* status.
**What could be the cause of this ?**

> Can below be the reasons?
>
> 1. Resource Limitations (CPU cores or memory)
> 2. ThreadPool TaskExecutor